# Как мне получить _client в discord.net?

Tags: c#, .net, discord

Я создал файл отвечающий за обработку сообщений

```
if (arg.Content != "")
                {
                    

                    var guild = arg.Channel as SocketGuildChannel;
                    SocketGuild guildCheck = client.GetGuild(guild.Guild.Id);
                    var channel = guildCheck.GetTextChannel(1067089425386971216);
                    

                    var embedBuilder = new EmbedBuilder().WithAuthor($"Автор: {arg.Author.Username}").WithDescription(
                                       $"**Канал**: {arg.Channel.Name}" +
                                       $"\n**Сообщение**: {arg.Content}" +
                                       $"\n \n **Время отправки**: {arg.CreatedAt.AddHours(3)}"
                                       ).WithColor(Color.Blue);
                     await channel.SendMessageAsync(embed: embedBuilder.Build());
                }
```

и подключаю его в главном файле

```
 _client = new DiscordSocketClient(config);

_client.SlashCommandExecuted += slashcommand.SlashCommandHandler;
_client.Ready += creatingCommand.Client_Ready;
_client.MessageReceived += message.checkMessage;
```

Из-за того что при подключении я использую _client моя функция не работает. Когда я пытаюсь подключить клиент при помощи  `DiscordSocketClient? client;` внутри файла с обработкой, ответ тот же. Но когда я вставляю в главный файл эту функцию, у меня все работает. Проблема в _client, как мне его получить без конфликтов между файлами?

Comment: Зачем вам клиент, если вы уже получили сервер в строке `var guild = arg.Channel as SocketGuildChannel;`? Вы понимаете вообще код, который написали? Вы получили сервер, спрашиваете у него id, а затем через этот id просите у клиента тож самый сервер, зачем..?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ разобрался и вы действительно оказались правы. Виноват, долго информация доходит :)

Answer (score 0):

Хм ок:
message.cs

```
public class MessageHandler
{
    private DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private ulong _channelId;

    public MessageHandler(DiscordSocketClient client, ulong channelId)
    {
        _client = client;
        _channelId = channelId;
    }

    public async Task CheckMessage(SocketMessage arg)
    {
        if (arg.Content != "")
        {
            var guild = (arg.Channel as SocketGuildChannel)?.Guild;
            var channel = guild?.GetTextChannel(_channelId);

            if (channel != null)
            {
                var embedBuilder = new EmbedBuilder()
                    .WithAuthor($"Автор: {arg.Author.Username}")
                    .WithDescription($"**Канал**: {arg.Channel.Name}" +
                                     $"\n**Сообщение**: {arg.Content}" +
                                     $"\n \n **Время отправки**: {arg.CreatedAt.AddHours(3)}")
                    .WithColor(Color.Blue);

                await channel.SendMessageAsync(embed: embedBuilder.Build());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Главный файл

```
_client = new DiscordSocketClient(config);
var channelId = 1067089425386971216UL;
var messageHandler = new MessageHandler(_client, channelId);

_client.SlashCommandExecuted += slashcommand.SlashCommandHandler;
_client.Ready += creatingCommand.Client_Ready;
_client.MessageReceived += messageHandler.CheckMessage;
```

Comment: Не кажется странным передавать объект клиента только в один метод, переопределяя событие целиком, нагружая его тем, что по умолчанию там нет? Может стоит сделать зависимость у класса `MessageHandler` тогда, да и подписание на получение события перенести внутрь этого класса... Не? Просто как-то ответ из разряда "моя хата с краю, надо, берите, остальное меня не волнует", без попытки даже разобраться, подсказать как правильно, и т.д. Вот может вы тогда ответите, зачем человек получает `Guild`, из которого берет Id, и запрашивает у клиента тот-же сервер (`Guild`)? Незнание == лишняя зависимость.

Comment: Жаль, что только после "пинка" начинается осмысление вопроса, и то не до конца. Зачем например теперь `_client` передается в `MessageHandler`? Он там нужен? Используется? У автора было недопонимание того, как получить канал сервера, вы без объяснений этот косяк исправили, выдав тупо код, и вот скажите, автор в дальнейшем будет знать как получить нужное? Думаю нет, он как и вы, бездумно скопирует полученное. Неужели сложно вот дать подробное объяснение, показать как надо, а как не следует, и почему? Будто через ChatGPT сгенерировали код и выкатили как есть ради репутации. Обидно, честно.